# Removing field value from embed issue

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm wanting to add a check to a embed field.
Currently when it's None it will just leave a `name="Steam"` value and a empty `value="[{result2[0]}](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{result2[0]})`.

I'm wanting to make a check to see if **result2** is in the database - I put an if statement `if result2:` before the embed field - if it does not return None it will show the embed field.` If result returns a None Type then don't show the embed field.

Not sure if this is possible.

Here is an example and a mockup edited in paint

- The one marked 1 is what results I'm getting if check returns `None`
- The one marked 2 is what result I get if the check returns a not
  `None`
- The one marked 3 is mocked up in paint version of what result
  I'd like to have if None is returned.

[image]

Here is the code I'm working with:

```py
@commands.group(invoke_without_command=True)
    async def profile(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
        user = user or ctx.author
        db = sqlite3.connect('profiles.sqlite')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT profile FROM profile WHERE username={user.id}")
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT steam FROM profile WHERE username={user.id}")
        result2 = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            await ctx.send(f"{user.display_name}'s bio has not been created yet.")
            return
        else:
            desc = f"**Bio:**\n{(result[0])}"
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{user.display_name}'s Profile", description=desc, color=user.colour)
            if result2: #here I add the check before adding the embed field
                embed.add_field(name="Steam", value=f"[{result2[0]}](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{result2[0]})")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `result2` is a list containing `None`, or something similar.  Let's directly check `result2[0]` as well as `result2`

```
        if result2 and result2[0]:
            embed.add_field(name="Steam", value=f"[{result2[0]}](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{result2[0]})")
```